# How can I change the output to a variable of this script

Tags: javascript

I have this script, which works fine. It finds the nearest place with your ip-address.
I just want to change this script to change a variable to the output. So not change an ID.

your town: callback();

```js
//var country = document.getElementById('country');
//var state = document.getElementById('state');
var city = document.getElementById('city');
//var postal = document.getElementById('postal');
//var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
//var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
//var ip = document.getElementById('ipv4');

function callback(data)
{
    //country.innerHTML = data.country_name;
    //state.innerHTML = data.state;
    city.innerHTML = '('+data.city+')';
    //postal.innerHTML = data.postal;
    //latitude.innerHTML = data.latitude;
    //longitude.innerHTML = data.longitude;
    //ip.innerHTML = data.IPv4;
}
document.getElementById("city").style.display = "block";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
h.parentNode.insertBefore(script, h);
```

I would like to use the script but call it to show the result, so not change a div id called city.
So I could show a google map with the city on the map displayed.

Comment: What "variable" did you want to change?

Comment: I would like to use the script but call it to show the result. So not change a <div id called city. So I could show a google map with the city on the map displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable and save data there, for example:

```
window.userInfo = {};
function callback(data){
        window.userInfo = data;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn’t see.